# Receiving Timestamps from PPS using uBLOX MAX M8C-0 GPS Receiver

Tags: pulse, gps, receiver

I am having problems with sending and receiving the messages. I am using the SDA and SCL lines. My goal it to try to use the PPS to get under 5 millisecond accuracy for timestamp purposes. Could someone please explain how you initialize the TimePulse pin so that the receiver would send you time data?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Paste the actual code into your question.